# How to read a ANSI text file and convert strings to UTF-8 in Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, encoding

I am trying to read text files with Ruby 1.9 and convert them into my own XML structure. I don't have control over the source text file so they could be in any encoding.

Here is what I do at the moment:

```
lines = File.readlines(input_file)
lines.each do |line|
  #do something
end
```

I have a problem with a file that contains the `é` character (xE9). When I try to process the corresponding line I get a `Invalid byte sequence in UTF-8` exception when I call `.match(...)` on the string.

I tried to use the workaround described at [Fixing invalid UTF-8 in Ruby, revisited](http://po-ru.com/diary/fixing-invalid-utf-8-in-ruby-revisited/)

```
lines = File.readlines(input_file)
ic = Iconv.new('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8')
lines.each do |line|
  unless line.empty?
   valid_string = ic.iconv(line + ' ')[0..-2]
   #do something
  end
end
```

but this simply strips the `é` character from the line which is not what I want.

I think the real problem is that the file itself doesn't seem to be in UTF-8 but uses some ANSI encoding. Although the file is not UTF-8 the resulting line object says it is UTF-8 when calling `.encoding`; My guess is that I need to use a different way to read the file so that it works for both ANSI and UTF-8 files but I am a Ruby beginner and I really don't know where to start.

Comment: What is this ANSI thing? Is that a made-up name?

Comment: I assume that this is the actual encoding: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 used by the file but I don't see a way to know that for sure in ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character is part of the ISO-8859-1 and Win-1252 character sets, among [others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Latin_character_sets_(computing)#Comparison_table). The second is probably the most popular character set for Windows, and is your most likely source.

```
RUBY_VERSION # => "1.9.2"
```

That's my Ruby version running the following tests. Note that in the following samples the `# encoding` lines aren't comments, they're directives to Ruby on which character set to use when unencoded binary characters are found:

```
# encoding: Windows-1252

RUBY_VERSION # => "1.9.2"

asdf = "\xe9"
asdf.encoding # => #<Encoding:Windows-1252>
asdf.encode('UTF-8') # => "é"
asdf.encode('UTF-8').encoding # => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

This shows the character in ISO-8859-1:

```
# encoding: ISO-8859-1

RUBY_VERSION # => "1.9.2"

asdf = "\xe9"
asdf.encoding # => #<Encoding:ISO-8859-1>
asdf.encode('UTF-8') # => "é"
asdf.encode('UTF-8').encoding # => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

James Gray did a [series of articles](http://graysoftinc.com/character-encodings) a couple years ago about dealing with this stuff. It's good reading.

Now, back to trying to figure out what character set a character could be in: When you only have one character, because it could be in several sets at once, it is difficult to determine which set it is. If you have more characters >= "\x80" then you can run through the characters sets `iconv` support and try converting them. That's messy, but I had to do that in Perl for some screen scraping about five years ago. An alternative is to use the Python [`chardet`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) code.

James Gray's articles have a link to an article recommending [`rchardet`](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/334884).

The above routines mention Mozilla's [Charset Detectors](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/intl/chardet.html), which will give you more info on dealing with this.

Answer (score 2):

you could try it on the console, this may be a hint:

I do it with a system command like this:

`iconv -f windows-1252 -t UTF-8 "#{csv_file}" > #{Rails.root}/tmp/Kdvakanz-utf8.csv`

Comment: surely, you want to use your encodings :)

Comment: but for that to work I would need to know what encoding the file is in, right?

Comment: @Patrick, of course. ANSI encodings don't have any information inside the files; Unicode has with the BOM (which on UTF-8 is a hack).